# Calling SharePoint 2013 REST API with FBA Turned On

Tags: rest, sharepoint, httpclient, fba

I have the following code which works perfectly fine with Forms Based Authentication turned off, but the moment I turn it on it stops working:

```
        string baseURL = siteUrl + "/_api/";
        string uriString = "web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/fields/getbyinternalnameortitle('" + displayName + "')";

        NetworkCredential cred = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Credentials = cred
        });

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
                SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        };

        HttpResponseMessage resp = client.GetAsync(uriString).Result;
        string respString = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

The response I get is as follows:

```
{StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0 
X-Forms_Based_Auth_Required:...)
```

I have tried several things, including specifying the farm account Windows Authentication credentials under on the HttpClient Credentials object, I have also tried to use the AuthenticationHeaderValue:

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", _FormatBasicAuth("domain", "username", "password"));
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing this issue I resolved it by going to Site Permissions and Setting Anonymous Access to Entire Website.